# how to add styles to all divs with a certain key word in their class css

Tags: html, css

I want to add styles to all `div`s with "cont" in their class. How can I do that? I tried with `div[class ~= "cont"]` but it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/infopersonal.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="cont-1">1</div>
        <div class="cont-2">2</div>
        <div class="cont-3">3</div>
        <div class="cont-4">4</div>
        <div class="div-5">5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ~ please use *
So your css definition would be as follow

div[class*="cont"]

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `^` if you want the string to begin with `cont` or `*` to verify the string in the class.

```css
div[class^="cont"] {
  background: red;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/infopersonal.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="cont-1">1</div>
        <div class="cont-2">2</div>
        <div class="cont-3">3</div>
        <div class="cont-4">4</div>
        <div class="div-5">5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```